# Understanding the line that calls the file name

Tags: perl, shell, filenames

I do not understand the line that calls the file name.

```
#!/bin/sh 
cd Desktop/Test/xml_replace   
find . -name "*.xml" -print | while IFS= read -r file; do echo "$file"   
perl -pi -e 's/&/&amp;/' $file
```

Comment: That's not a complete command. It is missing the closing `done` for the `while` loop. See [explainshell.com](http://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=find+.+-name+%22*.xml%22+-print+%7C+while+IFS%3D+read+-r+file%3B+do+echo+%22%24file%22++++perl+-pi+-e+%27s%2F%26%2F%26amp%3B%2F%27+%24file%3B+done).

Comment: Thanks for the reference website!! Let me check

Comment: What line do you need explained?

Comment: find. -name "*.xml" ..till "$file" - how does it recognize the name of the file in any path.

Comment: That's what `find` does. It walks one or more directory trees and takes some action (in this case, `-print`) on files matching some criteria (in this case, `-name "*.xml"`)

Comment: It might be interesting to note that the Perl code changes literal ampersands into HTML, which is a broken way to deal with HTML. Also, it only changes one `&` per line.

Comment: Thanks  mob and TLP for your explanation. Now I understood the & replace function too..